# Unhandled exception VS2010 C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unhandled-exception

I am trying to make a socket on windows to connect to a server.

I am using the code from msdn's website, the winsock client code. 
(Link: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737591(v=vs.100).aspx )

In any case, when I try debugging said code I get the error message:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x58a714cf (msvcr100d.dll) in Application.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000032.
```

It asks me if I want to break or continue, if I continue the same error message simply keeps popping up. If I press break it takes me to line 1643 in the file output.c .

Simply put, I have no idea about what to do to make it work, and I'd appreciate any help given.

EDIT:

A reply to all comments given thus far:

The surrounding relevant code in output.c is:

```
if (flags & (FL_LONG|FL_WIDECHAR)) {
                if (text.wz == NULL) /* NULL passed, use special string */
                    text.wz = __wnullstring;
                bufferiswide = 1;
                pwch = text.wz;
                while ( i-- && *pwch )
                    ++pwch;
                textlen = (int)(pwch - text.wz);
                /* textlen now contains length in wide chars */
            } else {
                if (text.sz == NULL) /* NULL passed, use special string */
                    text.sz = __nullstring;
                p = text.sz;
                while (i-- && *p) //THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS
                    ++p;
                textlen = (int)(p - text.sz);    /* length of the string */
            }
```

This is not code that I have written but innate code that already exists.

EDIT NR 2:
This is a printscreen displaying my call stack.
I do not have 10 reputation so I cannot show the image, so here is a link to the image:

http://tinypic.com/r/5n6ww9/5

On it you can see my call stack

Comment: have you tried running as either the program as admin or running VS with admin privleges?

Comment: So what is *"line 1643 in the file output.c"* and the relevant surrounding code?

Comment: I'm going to take a stab at people down voting your post and it is probably because you maybe forgot to post the relevant code as suggested by Roger

Comment: I bet you're trying to read a structure member from a null pointer to structure.

Comment: After clicking Break, look at the "Stack Trace" window in the debugger. It should tell you which function call crashes.

Comment: 0x00000032 is likely an offset to something, looks like you have a NULL pointer somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `output.c` has the code that handles the `printf` family of functions.

The fact that you have an error here is probably due to a malformed `printf` function call in your code. Maybe you have specified an invalid print format or have not provided enough arguments.

When your program crashes, click Break and look at the call stack in the debugging windows to see where - in your code - the function is called, and with what arguments.

I suspect you are trying to print a NULL string or something. When you have found the `printf` call (if that's what it is), edit your question to show that section of source code and/or use the debugger to examine the variables used a arguments to the function and make sure they are all correct.

Without seeing the code that you've written, at the location of the crash, it's not possible to give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

Or you may insert a null string to `CString.format` like below:

```
CString str;
str.format("%s"); //A null string
```

where it should be

```
str.format("%s",mes);
```

where `mes` is `char mes[20]` for example

or any other variable

So the point is there may be some mistake in `CString.format` or `Printf`

Good Luck.