# Visual Studio causing problems in c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I know it might be awkward to ask this type of question but really this bug is causing a lot of problem for me. I used the cpp mathematical parsing code from this link.**C++ Implementation of Basic Expression Parser**
http://www.technical-recipes.com/2011/a-mathematical-expression-parser-in-java-and-cpp/

Now I first compiled the code in Dev c++ . It compiled perfectly and I got the desired output
But when I created a visual c++ win32 console application and used the above code and I got the following errors
[image]

I got around 9 errors. I know that there might be some library issues that visual studio uses.
I am making a mathematical expression parsing app in windows. There somewhere it uses the **snprintf()** function which no longer exists in visual studio c library. Infact we have a **_snprintf()** function which doesn't provide the required functionality that I need and the app crashes in output.c file.

So how can we resolve this issue such that I can use the the  **snprintf()**  function in visual studio and how can we run the above code present in the link in win32 console app in Visual studio. I used visual studio 2012 and 2013. There are some more issues like **arc4random** doesn't work and we have to use **rand** and **srand** functions.

Searched a lot but unable to find the solution. Is it possible to change the compiler of my visual studio to C99 library where all these functions exist?
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

The code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int LEFT_ASSOC = 0;
const int RIGHT_ASSOC = 1;

// Map the different operators: +, -, *, / etc
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, int>> OpMap;
typedef std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator cv_iter;
typedef std::string::iterator s_iter;

const OpMap::value_type assocs[] = {
    OpMap::value_type("+", std::make_pair<int, int>(0, LEFT_ASSOC)),
    OpMap::value_type("-", std::make_pair<int, int>(0, LEFT_ASSOC)),
    OpMap::value_type("*", std::make_pair<int, int>(5, LEFT_ASSOC)),
    OpMap::value_type("/", std::make_pair<int, int>(5, LEFT_ASSOC))};

const OpMap opmap(assocs, assocs + sizeof(assocs) / sizeof(assocs[0]));

// Test if token is an pathensesis
bool isParenthesis(const std::string& token) {
    return token == "(" || token == ")";
}

// Test if token is an operator
bool isOperator(const std::string& token) {
    return token == "+" || token == "-" || token == "*" || token == "/";
}

// Test associativity of operator token
bool isAssociative(const std::string& token, const int& type) {
    const std::pair<int, int> p = opmap.find(token)->second;
    return p.second == type;
}

// Compare precedence of operators.
int cmpPrecedence(const std::string& token1, const std::string& token2) {
    const std::pair<int, int> p1 = opmap.find(token1)->second;
    const std::pair<int, int> p2 = opmap.find(token2)->second;

    return p1.first - p2.first;
}

// Convert infix expression format into reverse Polish notation
bool infixToRPN(const std::vector<std::string>& inputTokens, const int& size,
                std::vector<std::string>& strArray) {
    bool success = true;

    std::list<std::string> out;
    std::stack<std::string> stack;

    // While there are tokens to be read
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        // Read the token
        const std::string token = inputTokens[i];

        // If token is an operator
        if (isOperator(token)) {
            // While there is an operator token, o2, at the top of the stack AND
            // either o1 is left-associative AND its precedence is equal to that
            // of o2,
            // OR o1 has precedence less than that of o2,
            const std::string o1 = token;

            if (!stack.empty()) {
                std::string o2 = stack.top();

                while (isOperator(o2) && ((isAssociative(o1, LEFT_ASSOC) &&
                                           cmpPrecedence(o1, o2) == 0) ||
                                          (cmpPrecedence(o1, o2) < 0))) {
                    // pop o2 off the stack, onto the output queue;
                    stack.pop();
                    out.push_back(o2);

                    if (!stack.empty())
                        o2 = stack.top();
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            // push o1 onto the stack.
            stack.push(o1);
        }
        // If the token is a left parenthesis, then push it onto the stack.
        else if (token == "(") {
            // Push token to top of the stack
            stack.push(token);
        }
        // If token is a right bracket ')'
        else if (token == ")") {
            // Until the token at the top of the stack is a left parenthesis,
            // pop operators off the stack onto the output queue.
            std::string topToken = stack.top();

            while (topToken != "(") {
                out.push_back(topToken);
                stack.pop();

                if (stack.empty())
                    break;
                topToken = stack.top();
            }

            // Pop the left parenthesis from the stack, but not onto the output
            // queue.
            if (!stack.empty())
                stack.pop();

            // If the stack runs out without finding a left parenthesis,
            // then there are mismatched parentheses.
            if (topToken != "(") {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // If the token is a number, then add it to the output queue.
        else {
            out.push_back(token);
        }
    }

    // While there are still operator tokens in the stack:
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        const std::string stackToken = stack.top();

        // If the operator token on the top of the stack is a parenthesis,
        // then there are mismatched parentheses.
        if (isParenthesis(stackToken)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Pop the operator onto the output queue./
        out.push_back(stackToken);
        stack.pop();
    }

    strArray.assign(out.begin(), out.end());

    return success;
}

double RPNtoDouble(std::vector<std::string> tokens) {
    std::stack<std::string> st;

    // For each token
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)tokens.size(); ++i) {
        const std::string token = tokens[i];

        // If the token is a value push it onto the stack
        if (!isOperator(token)) {
            st.push(token);
        } else {
            double result = 0.0;

            // Token is an operator: pop top two entries
            const std::string val2 = st.top();
            st.pop();
            const double d2 = strtod(val2.c_str(), NULL);

            if (!st.empty()) {
                const std::string val1 = st.top();
                st.pop();
                const double d1 = strtod(val1.c_str(), NULL);

                // Get the result
                result = token == "+" ? d1 + d2 : token == "-"
                                                      ? d1 - d2
                                                      : token == "*" ? d1 * d2
                                                                     : d1 / d2;
            } else {
                if (token == "-")
                    result = d2 * -1;
                else
                    result = d2;
            }

            // Push result onto stack
            std::ostringstream s;
            s << result;
            st.push(s.str());
        }
    }

    return strtod(st.top().c_str(), NULL);
}

std::vector<std::string> getExpressionTokens(const std::string& expression) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string str = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)expression.length(); ++i) {
        const std::string token(1, expression[i]);

        if (isOperator(token) || isParenthesis(token)) {
            if (!str.empty()) {
                tokens.push_back(str);
            }
            str = "";
            tokens.push_back(token);
        } else {
            // Append the numbers
            if (!token.empty() && token != " ") {
                str.append(token);
            } else {
                if (str != "") {
                    tokens.push_back(str);
                    str = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}

// Print iterators in a generic way
template <typename T, typename InputIterator>
void Print(const std::string& message, const InputIterator& itbegin,
           const InputIterator& itend, const std::string& delimiter) {
    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    std::copy(itbegin, itend,
              std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, delimiter.c_str()));

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "(4*2/2-10)";

    Print<char, s_iter>("Input expression:", s.begin(), s.end(), "");

    // Tokenize input expression
    std::vector<std::string> tokens = getExpressionTokens(s);

    // Evaluate feasible expressions
    std::vector<std::string> rpn;
    if (infixToRPN(tokens, tokens.size(), rpn)) {
        double d = RPNtoDouble(rpn);
        Print<std::string, cv_iter>("RPN tokens:  ", rpn.begin(), rpn.end(),
                                    " ");

        std::cout << "Result = " << d << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Mis-match in parentheses" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of posting a screenshot of the errors, please copy-paste it instead. Also you should also show the code that causes the errors, including declarations of involved variables, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: VS is compiling the code using C++11 and the code probably was develop using C++98, the standard library of MS has big changes in `std::pair` type. What is the exact code with problem?

Comment: Hint: Don't ever specify the template arguments for `make_pair` when working with MSVC. Let the compiler deduce them - That was the entire point of `make_pair` anyway. That is the cause of those errors...

Comment: ok thanks..But the point of concern is I want to use the arc4random and snprintf functions in visual studio. Is there a way to change the compiler of visual studio.

Comment: `_snprintf` has always worked fine for me. You would have to specify your exact issue with it. As for `arc4random`, I can't find that as being part of any standard. The only random number generator specified in the C standard is `rand` as far as I can find. That means it is up to you to provide it or find a library which provides it if you wish to use it.

Comment: Do as @DarkFalcon say, remove the explicit instantiation of template parameter in `std::make_pair` as in `OpMap::value_type("+", std::make_pair(0, LEFT_ASSOC)),` the parameter would be deduced.

Comment: I downloaded the parsing code http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/expression_parser_cpp/ from here which uses BODMAS rule and gives proper result. It works fine on IOS(xcode) and android (eclipse). But the same cpp code doesn't work for visual studio due to cpp library problem. It has snprintf etc usage which when i replace by _snprintf() the app crashes in output.c. This link describes the exception http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840064/unhandled-exception-vs2010-c

Comment: "The fact that you have an error here is probably due to a malformed printf function call in your code. Maybe you have specified an invalid print format or have not provided enough arguments."